# Appcenter build 401 while fetching private repo package

Tags: github, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

We use appcenter.ms to build and deploy our mobile app.

This error began when I had to reconnect appcenter.ms to github using my account, the previous account was held by an employee who left the company.

When the build process runs yarn install, it 401s on the company's private repo.

```
yarn install v1.22.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning Pattern ["@apollo/client@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/Users/runner/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/npm-@apollo-client-3.4.7-63d7c3539cxxxxxxxxx9a8d1ad-integrity/node_modules/@apollo/client" as pattern ["@apollo/client@^3.3.18","@apollo/client@^3.0.0-beta.23","@apollo/client@^3.2.4","@apollo/client@^3.0.0-beta.24"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/xxxcompanyxxx/xxxprivaterepoxxx/0.0.10/6ebbf8b6583aaa977e798812d843a9989cd5498c1cf7e3dcedfb37cdd95e9ae6: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\"".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/runner/work/1/s/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

When I reconnected with my github, I had to rebuild the configuration (where you set the xcode version, .p12 cert, env variables, etc). I don't see any configuration options specific to github access or private repos there.

Is there a configuration step I'm missing, either on appcenter side or github?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. Appcenter uses `.npmrc` to authenticate via a Github personal access token. See this article:

https://blog.theodo.com/2018/07/installing-private-npm-packages-appcenter-2/

https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry#authenticating-with-a-personal-access-token

For me, this token had expired so I replaced it and that fixed my issue. If you're having similar issues, confirm that your `.npmrc` has a good token.